# Possible to index multiple products at a time? (Not all products at a time, not one at a time)

Tags: performance, indexing

Back in Magento 1.3x there was a programatic way to kick off the index processing for a list of products. But somewhere between 1.3.x and 1.6.x Magento's indexing code was refactored and I can't figure out how to get that same functionality.

It seems that in CE 1.6+ we have the option of kicking off an indexing process for *all* products, or we have the option to kick off the indexing process for a *single* product. But I have a list of products (ten to a couple hundred) that I want to reindex, but I don't want to run them individually if possible.

If it makes a difference, I am only interested in the pricing index process.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is.
I started looking to see what happens when you select multiple products in the grid and bulk change attributes.
In this method `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Action::updateAttributes()` some reindex event is registered.

```
Mage::getSingleton('index/indexer')->processEntityAction(
    $this, Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, Mage_Index_Model_Event::TYPE_MASS_ACTION
);
```

After digging deeper I ended up in this method for reindexing prices: `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price::catalogProductMassAction()`.
So if you want to trigger a price reindexing process just for a few products you can call this method in your code.

**Tip:** if you are trying to reindex more than 30% of your products it will trigger 'reindex all prices' process. (I'm really curious on who came up with this 30% and how).

Comment: Would you mind sharing which version of Magento you are working with? Seems like I looked at something similar, and I think the "indexer" code was refactored to be in the Mage_Index module rather than Mage_Catalog and Mage_CatalogIndex.

Comment: I checked for CE version 1.7.0.2

Comment: I've checked for 1.6.0.0 and 1.6.1.0 and it seams to work in the same way. For 1.5.x and 1.4.x is similar. Only the class name is different: Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Product_Indexer_Price. In version 1.3.x and lower I didn't find any price reindexing. But I didn't look hard enough because I didn't think it's that important.